# Java Tomcat SQL 2005 connection failed

Tags: sql-server, database, java, connection

I am in a bit of strange situation when it comes to debugging this issue.  I am working with a client who has a 3rd party administrate their servers, and that 3rd party does not allow for any changes in order to test but instead requires formal documentation for any change as well as justification as to why we are making the changes or else the change request gets rejected... Therefore I have to try to come up with conclusive answers without being able to change and test anything.

Therefore, any information/ speculation you guys have on this issue is useful.

I am using Java Tomcat to try to connect to a 64-bit MSSQL 2005 server and there's been no luck.  Does this log file indicate that there truly is no driver found, or is could it mean that the driver is found, but the the connection is not being accepted? Are they any other ways to interpret this error message?
I've been told that these connection configuration settings have worked for other server setups but for some reason I keep getting the below error.

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but the Tomcat server is 32-bit.  Is there a different driver to be able to connect to 64-bit as opposed to 32-bit MSSQL 2005?

```
 Login session = 5E3673D5B92737D27B9710CE28E37D66
    No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://serverName:1433;DatabaseName=DbName;user=DbUser;password=Password
    java.lang.Exception: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://serverName:1433;DatabaseName=DbName;user=DbUser;password=Password
        at com.medical.ConnectionPool.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspService(Login_jsp.java:135)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.medical.Utilities_Charset_Filter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
        at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:283)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:767)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:697)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:889)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not gotten to the point where the connection is being attempted.  There is either an issue with the driver you are trying to use or the configuration of Tomcat & the driver.  The error message is pretty clear.  It can't find a driver or use it.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem.  I got to check today, and it just had a typo for the SQL 2005 string.  Thanks